# SCVMM R2: Is there possibility to make P2V conversion on working Windows and synchronize changes made during conversion after whole process?

Tags: physical-to-virtual, scvmm

SCVMM R2: Is there possibility to make P2V conversion on working Windows and synchronize changes made during conversion after whole process?

Thanks

P.S. Destination is Hyper-V R2 Server.

Answer (score 1):

SCVMM uses the Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) to create an image of the source machine during the P2V process so it captures an image of the source at a single point in time. There is no option in SCVMM to force a synchronizaton of the source to the destination afterward. If you are trying to P2V a computer that changes a lot, you'll need to have some downtime and either turn off the source or stop all the services or IO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. 
Although i've never personally done it.

I've always been of a mindset that its best to minimize the IO activity on a server during a conversion - which is why we tend to convert ours at 2:00 am

But according to VMWare its totally possible.

**From VMWare Converter Standalone help file:**

Synchronize the Source with the Destination Machine
You can synchronize source and destination machines after the conversion of a powered-on machine is complete.
When cloning is finished, services are shut down and the source and destination machines are synchronized. Synchronization is available only for MS Windows XP or later source operating systems, managed destinations, and unmanaged EXS hosts. It is not available for OVF destinations.

Procedure

1

On the View/Edit Options page, click Advanced options.

2

Select Synchronize changes that occur to the source during cloning.

3

(Optional) VMware recommends that you select Power off source machine as well and specify the services to stop on the source during conversion.

4

Select another option to set or click Next to view a summary of the conversion task.
Converter Standalone synchronizes the destination machine with the source machine after the conversion is complete.**

Comment: And i apologize that it's not SCVMM R2 specific.

Comment: I know that VMware converter supports it but I need to convert machine to Hyper-V server so this solution will not work for sure :)